# Vsftpd 3.0.5 won’t allow virtual users login

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I’m trying to deploy the latest version of vsftpd and having difficulties with configuring virtual users and logging in to the FTP with them. I keep getting error 530 even though the users and passwords are correct. I have tried configuring virtual users with both Berkeley DB and htpasswd files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled verbose logging, and what do the logs say?

Comment: It says that login is incorrect and that I should login with user and password